# AngularJs - How to wait for HTML before running business logic in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular1.6

I have got an angular controller that calls a resource and then puts the result in to a variable.

Then in my HTML I am loping through the objects in that variable and rendering some HTML elements using ng-repeat.

The problem I'm having is, for each of the HTML elements being rendered I need to call a function which involves, getting the element by it's id.

At the point when I call this JS function, the elements have not been rendered yet.

This is the controller code.

```
cmsUserResource.GetOpCoUsersViewModel($routeParams.id.split("-")[1]).then(
  function (response) {

    vm.response = response;

    //This works because the HTML for this element is not generated dynamically
    Sortable.create(document.getElementById('advanced-1'), {
      sort: true,
      group: sortableOptions,
      animation: 200,
      onStart: function () {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('opCoUsersForm')).scope().opCoUsersForm.$dirty = true;
      }

    });


    vm.response.brands.forEach(function (brand) {
      //This DOES NOT work, the elements are not on the page yet.

      Sortable.create(document.getElementById('brand-' + brand.id), {
        sort: true,
        group: sortableOptions,
        animation: 200,
        onStart: function () {
          angular.element(document.getElementById('opCoUsersForm')).scope().opCoUsersForm.$dirty = true;
        }

      });
    });
  });
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="block__list">
  <div>
    <div class="formDefinitionPositionTitle">CMS Users in {{vm.response.opCo.companyName}} </div>
    <ul id="advanced-1" class="block__list_tags handle">
      <li umbracoUserId="{{cmsUser.cmsUserId}}" ng-repeat="cmsUser in vm.response.cmsUsers">{{cmsUser.cmsUserName}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Users In Brands</h3>
<div ng-repeat="brand in vm.response.brands">
  <div class="block__list">
    <div>
      <div class="formDefinitionPositionTitle">CMS Users in {{brand.brandName}} </div>
      <ul id="brand-{{brand.id}}" class="block__list_tags handle">
        <li umbracoUserId="{{cmsUser.cmsUserId}}" ng-repeat="cmsUser in brand.cmsUsers">{{cmsUser.cmsUserName}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
</div>
```

So how do I force angular to wait for the HTML before calling the:

```
Sortable.create(document.getElementById('brand-' + brand.id),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the lifecycle hooks (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) of AngularJS.

With Angular, you would use **AfterViewInit**, which would allow you to execute some code "*after the component's view has been fully initialized*".

So you need to find the equivalent for AngularJS, which would be the hook **$postLink()** from this documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: This looks promising... going to give this a try